# Как изменить текст используя одну функцию и три одинаковых элемента

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.title("Тест Лямбда")

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab1, text='вкладка-1')

btn1 = Button(tab1, text="1", command=lambda: printNum(1))
btn1.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=5, pady=10)

btn2 = Button(tab1, text="2", command=lambda: printNum(2))
btn2.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=5, pady=10)

btn = Button(tab1, text="3", command=lambda: changeBtn(3))
btn.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=5, pady=10)

btn = Button(tab1, text="4", command=lambda: changeBtn(4))
btn.grid(column=3, row=1, padx=5, pady=10)

quitBtn = Button(tab1, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=tab1.quit)
quitBtn.grid(column=4, row=1, padx=5, pady=10)

def printNum(num):
    print("Вы нажали кнопку: %s" % num)

def changeBtn(num):
    btn['text'] = '*'
    print("Вы нажали кнопку: %s" % num)

tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
window.mainloop()
```

Есть вот такой тестовый код. Задача при помощи лямбда функции изменить текст кнопки 3 и 4 при помощи одной универсальной функции, но не понимаю почему при нажатии на 3 текст меняется в 4. Понятно что функция берет последнюю кнопку и меняет её, но я что то не силён в лямбда.

P.S. Это фокус подходит для вызова функции по нажатии кнопки, но не для метода .config (.configure) в Tkinter. То есть, есть рабочий код где есть цикл в котором каждая итерация выводит Label Button(+лямбда) + есть универсальная функция корректно выполняющая инструкции кроме .config (.configure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто передавайте экземпляр кнопки в функцию `changeBtn` дополнительным аргументом.

```py
btn3 = Button(tab1, text="3", command=lambda: changeBtn(3, btn3))
btn4 = Button(tab1, text="4", command=lambda: changeBtn(4, btn4))
```

```py
def changeBtn(num, btn):
    btn['text'] = '*'
    print("Вы нажали кнопку: %s" % num)
```

#### Upd

В цикле можно сделать так

```py
for i in range(10):
    button = Button(tab1, text=str(i + 1))
    button.config(command=lambda button=button, idx=i: changeBtn(idx + 1, button))
    button.grid(column=i, row=1, padx=5, pady=10)
```

Либо создать список кнопок и обращаться к ним по индексу, тогда нужно немного изменить обработчик.

```py
buttons = []
for i in range(10):
    button = Button(tab1, text=str(i + 1), command=lambda idx=i: changeBtn(idx + 1, idx))
    button.grid(column=i, row=1, padx=5, pady=10)
    buttons.append(button)
```

```py
def changeBtn(num, idx):
    buttons[idx]['text'] = '*'
    print("Вы нажали кнопку: %s" % num)
```

Comment: Не подходит, переменные должны быть одноименные. У меня нет возможности генерировать имена переменных в цикле, потому что я не умею так делать )))))

Comment: @ЕвгенийДолбановский Что значит должны? Не должны и не могут. Приложите задание, где указано это требование.

Comment: @ЕвгенийДолбановский подставьте мои строчки кода вместо своих соответсвующих. Надпись нажатой кнопки будет заменяться на `*`. Если это не то, что вам нужно, уточните вопрос.

Comment: Согласен конечно, переменные не должны. Но как тогда быть, надо или делать вывод так:
Button(tab1, text="3", command=lambda: changeBtn(3)).grid(column=2, row=1, padx=5, pady=10)
Button(tab1, text="4", command=lambda: changeBtn(4)).grid(column=3, row=1, padx=5, pady=10)

Но тогда не понятно как функция будет менять текст кнопки, привязаться то не к чему, но точнее есть, но я пока не соображу как:

    def changeBtn(num):
         Button.configure(text="*")
         print("Вы нажали кнопку: %s" % num)

Comment: @ЕвгенийДолбановский Но **зачем** вам делать так? Так привязаться действительно особо не к чему, чем плох вариант в две строки?

Comment: Он плох тем, что у меня Label и Button генерируются из цикла. Вот если бы я мог задавать имя переменной прям в цикле, то и проблем бы не было. Но насколько я понял создавать имя переменной на основании данных цикла плохая идея

Comment: Или тогда как из значений списка [] ключ:значение сделать имя переменной ?

Comment: @ЕвгенийДолбановский обновил ответ.